# Angular is not sending any request to Node server

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express

I am trying to build a MEAN stack application and i don't know why Angular is not sending any post request. When i try to post request using insomnia, it works fine. However its not the case with angular.
Plus the issue lies in the LoginPlayer function. Rest of them are fine.
**web-service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import Player from 'src/models/Player';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebService {
  player:Player
  readonly ROOT_URL;
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
    this.ROOT_URL='http://localhost:3000'
   }
   post(uri:string,payload:Player)
   {
     const obj={
      FullName:payload.FullName,
      Email:payload.Email,
      Password:payload.Password,
      Gender:payload.Gender,
     }
     return this.http.post(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`,obj);
   }
   LoginPlayer(uri:string,Email:String,Password:String)
   {
      const obj1={
          Email:Email,
          Password:Password
      }

     return this.http.post(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`,obj1);
   }

   get(uri:string){
     return this.http.get(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`)
   }
}
```

**Player-Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { WebService } from './web.service';
import Player from 'src/models/Player';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PlayerService {
  Player:Player
  constructor(private WebService:WebService) { }
  createPlayer(player:Player){
    return this.WebService.post(`Players`,player)
  }
  getPlayers()
  {
    return this.WebService.get('Players')
  }
  LoginPlayer(Email:String,Password:String){
    return this.WebService.LoginPlayer(`players/Login`,Email,Password)
  }
}
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const header = require('body-parser')
const router = express.Router()
const player = require('./Players')
const mongoose = require('./dbConfig')
app.use(express.json())
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,PATCH,DEL");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server started at 3000'))
app.post('/Players/Login', (req, res) => {
    player.find({ Email: req.body.Email, Password: req.body.Password })
        .then(player => console.log(player))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));


});
app.post('/Players', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file);
    (new player({ 'Name': req.body.Name, 'Email': req.body.Email, 'Password': req.body.Password, 'Gender': req.body.Gender, 'Sports': req.body.Sports }))
    .save()
        .then((player) => console.log(player))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error))
});
app.patch('/Players/:Email', (req, res) => {
    player.findOneAndUpdate({ Email: req.params.Email }, { $push: { Sports: req.body.Sports } })
        .then(player => res.send(player))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
});
app.get('/Players', (req, res) => {
    player.find({})
        .then(player => res.send(player))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));

});
```

Comment: You're not subscribing to the observable returned from the service. http calls won't fire unless you subscribe to them.

Answer (score 1):

You are not subscribing to the Observable:

https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

What you should do in the `component` or `service` that is going to call the `PlayerService` is:

```
playerService.getPlayers().subscribe(
   (data) => {
    // Successs
    // Data is the result of your http request.
   } 

);
```